# Kubuntu 16.04 + Bumblebee Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I upgraded Kubuntu from 15.10, installed `bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-364`

`optirun glxgears` is working, but i can't run any game with steam

```
juin 18 15:15:10 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1258.527072] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

juin 18 15:15:10 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1258.527077] [WARN][XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.

juin 18 15:15:10 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1258.527080] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mouse

juin 18 15:15:10 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1258.527082] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

juin 18 15:15:46 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1294.315083] [WARN][XORG] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.

juin 18 15:15:46 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1294.315095] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mouse

juin 18 15:15:46 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1294.315100] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

juin 18 15:15:46 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1294.315106] [WARN][XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.

juin 18 15:15:46 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1294.315109] [WARN][XORG] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mouse

juin 18 15:15:46 kwaadpepper-pc bumblebeed[31999]: [ 1294.315111] [ERROR][XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)
```

I compiled xserver-xorg-input-mouse but i depended on ABI 21 something so, bumblebee could not work, using ABI 22 on 16.04.

Is anyone having this, or any clue here ?

Here is the package installed https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-mouse/1:1.9.1-1/+build/6508811

there is no xenial amd64 package so i took the willy one that depends on `xorg-input-abi-21` .

Answer (score 4):

Please don't install any packages.

Just edit the file /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia to include the following screen-section to make bumblebee work:

```
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Default Screen"
  Device "DiscreteNvidia"
EndSection
```

(To open the file for editing, run `sudo kate /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` )

After a restart of bumblebee, it works properly.