# Ubuntu 16.04.1 bumblebee mouse module

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

When i try to run:

```
primusrun glxgears
```

I get the following error:

```
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)
```

I tried to add this:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Default Screen"
Device "DiscreteNvidia"
EndSection
```

to xorg.conf.nvidia as it is explain here [Kubuntu 16.04 + Bumblebee Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788532/kubuntu-16-04-bumblebee-failed-to-load-module-mouse-module-does-not-exist) but the only thing i get when i change the xorg.conf.nvidia to that and restart bumblebeed.service is:

```
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Problem parsing the config file
```

Neither primusrun or optirun work, they give the same error.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a solution for you, but I'll post anyway.

Is there a reason for you to use bumblebee besides not having to log out and log in? If the reason is energy consumption, which is high when not using bbswitch, I've coded a version of prime-indicator with power management capabilities, which can be found here: https://github.com/andrebrait/prime-indicator.

I've tested it quite a lot since yesterday and I've had no problems with it, with the benefit of having less bugs and better power consumption than with bumblebee. The only caveat is having to log out and log in again in order to switch the active GPU.

Comment: I should note that, by default, if using the the NVIDIA drivers up to version 361, Ubuntu itself turns the NVIDIA card off by default.